# Allow CORS with Mojolicious::Plugin::SecureCORS

Tags: perl, cors, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

I am new to Mojolicious and using plugins especially `SecureCORS`.
How can I allow CORS on POST requests?

I managed to allow CORS for GET with following lines:

```pl
use Mojolicious::Lite;

app->plugin('SecureCORS');
app->routes->to('cors.origin' => '*');
```

I thought `'cors.origin' => '*'` is allowing CORS for all methods but it works only for GET.

Maybe there is another or better way to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and allow all POST, GET, PUT, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frankly said, I have not used SecureCors plugin but I faced the same problem of cross-origin problem while developing the REST API's in Mojolicious.

Note:- I am not using the Mojolicious::lite app.

You might need to do something more or less similar to this, under your startup subroutine (If not using Mojolicious::Lite).

```
$self->hook(after_dispatch => sub { 
    my $c = shift; 
    $c->res->headers->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*'); 
    $c->res->headers->access_control_allow_origin('*');
    $c->res->headers->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'GET, OPTIONS, POST, DELETE, PUT');
    $c->res->headers->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

});
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a hard time making it work. It's not about POST vs GET, but about simple vs preflighted requests.

When you load `SecureCORS` (`plugin 'SecureCORS'`), it [subscribes](https://github.com/powerman/perl-Mojolicious-Plugin-SecureCORS/blob/v2.0.4/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/SecureCORS.pm#L39) to the `after_render` hook. And at the end of each request it [checks](https://github.com/powerman/perl-Mojolicious-Plugin-SecureCORS/blob/v2.0.4/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/SecureCORS.pm#L143) if `cors.origin` was specified for the current (or parent) route(s), if it's a [CORS request](https://github.com/powerman/perl-Mojolicious-Plugin-SecureCORS/blob/v2.0.4/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/SecureCORS.pm#L151) (the `Origin` header is present), and whether the `Origin` header's value [matches](https://github.com/powerman/perl-Mojolicious-Plugin-SecureCORS/blob/v2.0.4/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/SecureCORS.pm#L155-L163) `cors.origin`. If so, it [adds](https://github.com/powerman/perl-Mojolicious-Plugin-SecureCORS/blob/v2.0.4/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/SecureCORS.pm#L165-L171) `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, and possibly `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`, `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`.

To deal with preflighted requests you need to use the [`cors`](https://github.com/powerman/perl-Mojolicious-Plugin-SecureCORS/blob/v2.0.4/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/SecureCORS.pm#L26-L37) shortcut. It defines an [`OPTIONS` route](https://github.com/powerman/perl-Mojolicious-Plugin-SecureCORS/blob/v2.0.4/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/SecureCORS.pm#L29) for the specified URL. It takes options either from the `OPTIONS` route [itself](https://github.com/powerman/perl-Mojolicious-Plugin-SecureCORS/blob/v2.0.4/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/SecureCORS.pm#L69-L78), or from the [target one](https://github.com/powerman/perl-Mojolicious-Plugin-SecureCORS/blob/v2.0.4/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/SecureCORS.pm#L80-L89). Again it checks if `cors.origin` is [provided](https://github.com/powerman/perl-Mojolicious-Plugin-SecureCORS/blob/v2.0.4/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/SecureCORS.pm#L93-L95), if the `Origin` header's value [matches](https://github.com/powerman/perl-Mojolicious-Plugin-SecureCORS/blob/v2.0.4/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/SecureCORS.pm#L100-L109) `cors.origin`, if `Access-Control-Request-Headers` [matches](https://github.com/powerman/perl-Mojolicious-Plugin-SecureCORS/blob/v2.0.4/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/SecureCORS.pm#L111-L122) `cors.headers`. If so it [adds](https://github.com/powerman/perl-Mojolicious-Plugin-SecureCORS/blob/v2.0.4/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/SecureCORS.pm#L124-L134) `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, and possibly `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`, `Access-Control-Max-Age`.

In other words to allow CORS for all requests, you do `app->routes->to('cors.origin' => '...', ...);`, and `app->routes->cors('/some/path')` for every preflighted request.

To give you an example here's an app that handles requests for two domains (e.g. `a.example.com` and `b.example.com`). When you open http://a.example.com, it does two requests to `b.example.com` (a simple and preflighted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojolicious::Lite -signatures;
plugin 'SecureCORS';

app->routes->to('cors.origin' => '*');

get '/' => sub ($c) {
  $c->render;
} => 'index';

get '/simple' => sub ($c) {
  $c->render(text => '');
};

app->routes->cors('/preflight');
del '/preflight' => {'cors.headers' => ''} => sub ($c) {
  $c->render(text => '');
};

app->start;
__DATA__

@@ index.html.ep
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  <script>
    fetch('http://b.example.com/simple')
      .then(r => console.log(r))
      .then(() =>
        fetch('http://b.example.com/preflight', {method: 'DELETE'})
          .then(r => console.log(r))
      )
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Files needed to run it under `docker` can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/f0d85f16c952a743434358e29ec06398).

Another issue here is that it makes sense to define `cors.headers` for preflighted routes. Although it works anyway, it triggers a [warning](https://github.com/powerman/perl-Mojolicious-Plugin-SecureCORS/blob/v2.0.4/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/SecureCORS.pm#L118):

> Use of uninitialized value $opt{"headers"} in split at /app/local/lib/perl5/Mojolicious/Plugin/SecureCORS.pm line 118.

And while the preflight route can gather the `cors.*` options from the [target route](https://github.com/powerman/perl-Mojolicious-Plugin-SecureCORS/blob/v2.0.4/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/SecureCORS.pm#L80-L89) (if there's [no `cors.origin`](https://github.com/powerman/perl-Mojolicious-Plugin-SecureCORS/blob/v2.0.4/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/SecureCORS.pm#L69) on the preflight route), the target route can only rely on itself. That is, if there are no global/parent settings, and you define `cors.origin` on the preflight route, you should also do so on the target route:

```
app->routes->cors('/preflight')->to('cors.origin' => '*');
del '/preflight' => {'cors.origin' => '*'} => sub ($c) {
  $c->render(text => '');
};
```

(Make sure you disable cache when experimenting, preflight requests are cached.)

Answer (score 1):

defined to allow CORS, either here or in the parent routes. to set CORS options for this route at least origin option must be.

```
$r->get(…, {'cors.origin' => '*'}, …);
$r->any(…)->to('cors.origin' => '*');
```

allow non-simple (with preflight) CORS on this route

```
$r->cors(…);
```